# How to parameterize datestamp in pyODBC query?

Tags: python, pyodbc, qodbc

I'm using [`pyodbc`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) together with [`QODBC`](http://qodbc.com/) to construct an ODBC query.

I'm having trouble inserting datestamp parameters. Here you can see the escalation starting from the literal version (1) to string-format version (2) to error-state versions. (**Note `DateFrom` & `DateTo`**):

1. `sql = "sp_report ProfitAndLossStandard show Amount_Title, Text, Label, Amount parameters DateFrom = {d'2018-02-12'}, DateTo = {d'2018-02-18'}, SummarizeColumnsBy='TotalOnly', ReturnRows='All'"`
2. `sql = "sp_report ProfitAndLossStandard show Amount_Title, Text, Label, Amount parameters DateFrom = %s, DateTo = %s, SummarizeColumnsBy='TotalOnly', ReturnRows='All'" % (q_startdate, q_enddate)`

Subsequent attempts with the insertion syntax `?`, `cursor.execute(sql, (q_startdate), (q_enddate))` and the variables:

```
q_startdate = ("{d'%s'}" % dates[0])
q_enddate = ("{d'%s'}" % dates[1])
```

3. `sql = "sp_report ProfitAndLossStandard show Amount_Title, Text, Label, Amount parameters DateFrom = ?, DateTo = ?, SummarizeColumnsBy='TotalOnly', ReturnRows='All'"`

`>>> ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] SQL data type out of range (0) (SQLBindParameter)')`

```
q_startdate = (dates[0])
q_enddate = (dates[1])
```

4. `sql = "sp_report ProfitAndLossStandard show Amount_Title, Text, Label, Amount parameters DateFrom = {d'?'}, DateTo = {d'?'}, SummarizeColumnsBy='TotalOnly', ReturnRows='All'"`

`>>> ('42000', "[42000] [QODBC] [sql syntax error] Expected lexical element not found: = {d'?'} (11015) (SQLPrepare)")`

Reading the `pyodbc` [Wiki page on inserting data](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started#inserting-data), I don't read about any speed bumps with insertion strings. This must have something to do with how pyodbc processes (escapes) the datestamp.

How do you parameterize datestamp--Especially with the `qodbc` [flavor of datestamp](https://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/knowledgebase/article/View/2203/0/qodbc-desktop-how-are-dates-formatted-in-sql-queries-when-using-the-quickbooks-generated-timestamps).

Comment: Does your query work if your parameter values are true Python [date](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) values (e.g., `q_startdate = date(2018, 2, 12)`) and you simply use `... DateFrom = ?` ...?

Comment: That works. Thanks. If you want, make that an answer and I'll give you the correct answer points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost never necessary to use ODBC escape sequences like `{d'2018-02-12'}` in a pyodbc parameterized query. If the parameter value is a true Python [date](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) object

```python
q_startdate = date(2018, 2, 12)
```

then pyodbc will inform the ODBC driver that the parameter value is a `SQL_TYPE_DATE` as shown in the ODBC trace log

```
[ODBC][2984][1532535987.825823][SQLBindParameter.c][217]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x1f1a6b0
            Param Number = 1
            Param Type = 1
            C Type = 91 SQL_C_TYPE_DATE
            SQL Type = 91 SQL_TYPE_DATE
            Col Def = 10
            Scale = 0
            Rgb Value = 0x1f3ac78
            Value Max = 0
            StrLen Or Ind = 0x1f3ac58
```

and we can just use a bare parameter placeholder in our SQL command text

```sql
... parameters DateFrom = ?, ...
```