# Query database with parameter using pandas.read_sql

Tags: sql, pandas, oracle, parameter-passing, pyodbc

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60384058/read-database-into-dataframe-using-pyodbc-with-parameterized-query) was asked. 
The goal is to create the function described here:

```
def DB_Query(d1, d2):
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=DATASOURCE')
    tbl = "SELECT TableA.Field_1 \
    FROM TableA \
    WHERE TableA.Date>=? AND TableA.Date<=?"
    df_tbl= pd.read_sql_query(tbl, conn, params = (d1,d2))
    conn.close
    return df_tbl
```

This worked on database with SQL Server driver, but it won't work on Microsoft ODBC for Oracle driver.

When I give, for e.g., `d1 = '2020-02-20'` and `d2 = '2020-02-25'`, I get error
`('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] SQL data type out of range (0) (SQLBindParameter)')`

I understand in Oracle, you need `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'` to express a date, which is different from SQL server where you can just use `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

I've tried add `DATE` in front of `?` but doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found solution here. Just define `d1` as `date(2020,02,20)`.

[How to parameterize datestamp in pyODBC query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489632/how-to-parameterize-datestamp-in-pyodbc-query)